# Setting TextView to a TableRow, IllegalStateException - Android

Tags: java, android, textview, tablerow, illegalstateexception

I am trying to implement a highscores table using SQLite for my trivia game.  I commented in the error I am getting into my code.

I am not using those views mentioned in the error anywhere else so I do not know why I am getting that error.

Highscores.java

```
public class Highscores extends Activity {

    DatabaseHelper dh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor percentages, scores;
    TableLayout table;
    TableRow rowHeader, row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, row10;
    TextView rank, percentage, score;
    Button btn1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.highscoresmain);

        dh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        db = dh.openDB();
        percentages = dh.getPercentage(db);
        scores = dh.getScore(db);

        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.homeBtn);

        TableRow rowHeader = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.rowHeader);
        TableRow row1 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row1);

        TextView rank = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rank);
        TextView percentage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage);
        TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);

        TextView r1r = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.r1r);
        TextView r1p = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.r1p);
        TextView r1s = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.r1s);

        rank.setText("TEST - COLUMN RANK");
        percentage.setText("TEST - COLUMN PERCENTAGE");
        score.setText("TEST - COLUMN SCORE");
        r1r.setText("test..rank");
        r1p.setText("teset...percentage");
        r1s.setText("test...scoree");

        rowHeader.addView(rank);  //IllegalStateException:  The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        rowHeader.addView(percentage);
        rowHeader.addView(score);

        row1.addView(r1r);
        row1.addView(r1p);
        row1.addView(r1s);

        table.addView(rowHeader);
        table.addView(row1); 

        table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        dh.closeDB(db);
    }
}
```

highscoresmain.xml

```
<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id = "@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/rowHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rank"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/percentage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/r1r"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/r1p"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/r1s"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</TableLayout>
```

LogCat

```
01-02 15:21:10.870: W/dalvikvm(901): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Highscores}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3378)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3249)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3194)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3170)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at com.example.test.Highscores.onCreate(Highscores.java:73)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-02 15:21:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  ... 11 more
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is quite clear:

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException`: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

That's `rank`, it already has a parent, `rowHeader` its is parent. Those views are already within the `TableRow` elements, as you specified in your layout. You don't need to re-add them, and in fact you can't.